# Categories name on navigation on twentyten theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress and using twentyten theme. I have created categories and child categories. now i want to show these categories name on navigation bar instead of pages.

Can anybody have idea how to do this.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should ask this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com, but the answer can be found in the WordPress Codex at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashboard->Appearance->Menus

You can place Pages and Categories into your own custom Navigation this way, and it's VERY easy to use.

If you're interested, here's some [Relevant Code](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) on Navigation Menus, and here's some information on the [Menus Subpanel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel)